# How to make images fit Table Row in Android?

Tags: android

I have just started out working with Android and I have been working on a project for 6 hours today. I cannot figure out how to make images scale correctly on a `TableRow` to fill the horizontal width of the screen. I have this :

[image: Screen 1]

but I'd like this:

[image: Screen 2]

How do I get the fruit to stretch like this and fill the row? I tried setting the `TableLayout` to stretch columns 1,2,3,4,5 but it just spreads them out and the image doesn't increase. I read in the Android API guide that the child Row will take on properties of the parent Layout, so I'm thinking it might be a property in the Layout, but I can't find the right property. Or is the `TableLayout` not supposed to be inside the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Just apply fix width for your imageview and apply `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: I tried that doing fitXY but it didn't change the scale. What do you mean fix width?

Comment: Then you can apply weight property equally to your imageviews using linearlayout.

Comment: So I need to change my layout?

Comment: Are your all images in TableRow??

Comment: Yes. I have 5 separate imageView per row

Comment: Just apply `android:layout_weight` property to your all imageview equally and their `width` must be `0dp`.

Comment: use Grid View  instead of Table

Comment: @PiyushGupta that's what it was. Weight! Thank you!

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus Your wel come!!!

Comment: @PiyushGupta Is there anyway to stretch the image vertically? Say I want 5 rows and I want the rows to fill the screen, how would I adjust the rows to stretch vertical? Is there another weight property or something?

Comment: For that you need to use `LinearLayout` which have `horizontal` and `vertical` orientation. so while you need to vertically you can apply `vertical` orientation and use weight property.